# How can I fix a dish that has been over sweetened?

Tags: sweeteners

I often made a mistake while cooking that my sweet dishes gets over sweetened.(specially while making sweet rice,sheer khorma and custard) Is there any way/trick to fix the over sweetened dish?

Comment: Welcome! Is there a specific sort of recipe or dish that you have trouble with most of the time? The fix may be different for different foods...

Comment: Not a fix, but if you're experiencing it often, then either follow a tried & tested recipe for the amount of sugar to use, or add in small increments. Note down the amounts you used and use less the next time.

Answer (score 2):

For desserts, you can always add a sauce or topping that is bitter or sour to balance out the sweetness. Citrus, roasted nuts, dried chiles, dark chocolate, or coffee would all help a cloying dessert.